# Alias to external FAT32 drive in Apache gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, alias

I have a website that needs to allow some downloads of some very large files that are on an external hard drive. I've made an alias and it works, but I just get "403 forbidden" whenever I try to look at anything on the hard drive. I tried chmod and chown to solve the problem, but they don't work on a FAT drive. Reformatting the drive or putting everything on the internal hard drive is not an option as there is nowhere else with enough space to put all these files. Can someone please tell me how to make Apache access them?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually. I had to unmount the drive, recreate the drive's folder under "/media" and chown:chgrp it for www-data, and then remount the drive manually setting the user and group id to www-data.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to setup a <Directory> tag to allow access to the directory.